# How do websites validate username and passwords and obtain data?

Tags: php, ios, web

I have a question that is more conceptual at the moment than anything else.

**Here's my situation**

The school that I go to has a website for grade viewing which can be found at this link: https://grades.bsd405.org/Pinnacle/Gradebook/InternetViewer/Default.aspx

The login page presents a username and password box.

I plan on constructing a simple iPhone app that takes the resultant grades that are listed and display them in a UITableView.

However, how would I achieve getting the data from this website?

How do websites validate **(authenticate)** usernames and passwords and then pass on the relevant data?

Thanks for bearing through this tough question.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have access to their actual database? If not the site may offer an API and/or OAuth.

Comment: Yes, I don't have access to the database unfortunately. could you please explain what an API or OAuth does?

Comment: Some sites offer APIs (application programming interface) - basically exposing certain methods so that you can get/set data. Generally (especially in the last few years) most secure sites require you to authenticate first using [OAuth protocol](http://oauth.net/), before you are able to get/set using the API. Not sure if this site provides an API but that would be really the only way to get data from them real-time. Otherwise they may allow you to export data to a spreadsheet or CSV which you could parse and save externally on a regular basis or something.

Comment: Thank you, I will do some more research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things going on in this website; i think we would need a little more info from you on your specific request.  When you say Validate, do you mean validate as in check that usernames and passwords are formatted correctly or do you mean validate as in authenticate, i.e. send the resultant data to the X to determine that the username and password is correct.

Based on what I see I can partially answer your question, the asp site would send over SSL, the user name and password to the application, where I would assume the application then checks the username and password against a username and hash of the password (the hash being the calculated squish of the password which is stored as such for security and confidentiality).

In your case you wouldn't need to know any of that if you wanted to interface/integrate an app with this, you'd just need to format a request in your app and deliver it over an SSL connnection to the page.  There's a caveat; and that being session stuff with ASP; its a bit more complex than just usernames and passwords.

Comment: Yes, I need to authenticate the user once the username and passwords are submitted so that I can retrieve the data to display. Could you list some sources that I could look at for more info? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The page generate a **unique ID** each time, passed as **hidden field** of the form. So i'm sorry but i think that you can't post nothing from the extern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you certain can pass the hidden id.

What you need to do is follow the session stuff that ASP generates.  We do this all the time with ASP sites that we 'scrape' for data with our primary application.

Your app will first need to call the site, collect the sessionid data, and return that in your form when you submit the form for authentication.  After that depending on what is happening in the site, you may need to capture and send the resultant sessionid on each subsequent request.

Actually its a horrible thing when you see how much useless data is passed back and forth by ASP.